# What is $f(2016)$?

Tags: mathematics, functional-equation

Let $f: \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z $ be a function such that $$f(34f(x)+78)=57$$

1. What is $f(2016)$?
2. Do we know any other value of $f$ for sure?

This is one of my own problems.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So, first of all

> take any $x$ and write $y=34f(x)+78$; then $f(y)=57$ and $f(34f(y)+78)=57$; since $f(y)=57$ the latter says $f(2016)=57$.

Does f have to map everything to 57? Well,

> let 
>  $$f(x) = \begin{cases} 57 && \mathrm{if} \, x \equiv 78 \mod 34 \\ 0 && \mathrm{otherwise} \end{cases}$$ 
> Then it is clearly true that $f(34f(x)+78)=57$ for any $x$. So no, $f$ needn't be constant.

Now,

> that doesn't tell us whether $f(2016)$ is the only value that's required to be $57$. There certainly must be other values of $f$ that equal $57$. To see this, suppose $f(x)$ isn't $57$ (if we can't find an $x$ with this property then $f$ is always 57); then $f(34f(x)+78)=57$ but $34f(x)+78$ isn't $2016$.

But

> we can construct solutions as follows. Pick any $t$ that isn't $57$. Now set $f(2016)=f(34t+78)=57$ and $f(\text{everything else})=t$. This satisfies the given condition because $f(x)$ is always either $57$ or $t$, and hence $34f(x)+78$ is always either $2016$ or $34t+78$, and hence $f(34f(x)+78)=57$ as required. But any two of these functions have different values of $34t+78$ and hence disagree everywhere except at $f(2016)$. Therefore, we do not know the value of any other $f(x)$.

Comment: i think f( f(x) ) is a recursion. in this example, i see x= 34f(x)+78

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not sure what you mean. Could you be more specific about what you think I've said that's wrong? I don't *think* I've said x=34f(x)+78 anywhere...

Comment: nono, i dont think you are wrong. sorry. i mean, can you explain me why that function is not recursive? f inside an f . ?

Comment: A recursive definition is one that tells you f(x) in terms of other f(...) things. This isn't really a property of the *function* but of how you write down its definition. E.g., consider the Fibonacci numbers: f(0)=0, f(1)=1, f(n)=f(n-1)+f(n-2). That's a recursive definition but you can define the same function by $f(n)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{5}}\left(\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n-\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n\right)$.

Comment: okk.. my math is a bit rusty ^^'

Comment: So, anyway, what we have in the problem statement here isn't a *definition* at all. Rather, we're being asked what we can say about a function given a fact about it: that for any x, f(34f(x)+78)=57. It turns out that that's nowhere near enough to define the function; there are lots of functions satisfying that condition.

Comment: So it doesn't really make sense to say that it is or isn't recursive; being recursive is a property of a definition of a function, and we don't have one. (Or, relatedly, being recursive is a property of an *implementation* of a function on a computer. We don't have one of those here either.)

Answer (score 4):

> f(n) = 57
>  1. f(2016) = 57
>  2. Yes, we know all the values, they are 57. :p

Comment: one doubt if f(x) is number f(34*f(x)+78) will be f(some number) which is equal to 57 , how it is a constant function ?

Comment: because the result is not x dependant. no matter the content of "f", the answer is 57

Comment: Are you suggesting that this is the _only_ solution? Any explanations supporting this idea?

Comment: i saw "f( g(x) )= whatever". but never (i think)  "f( f(x) ) = whatever" is like recursion

Comment: Isn't this a math problem??

Comment: @elias No, it's not the only solution. There are infinite solutions. For example: f(x) = 57 iff x is even and f(x) = 0 iff x is odd. (You can change f(x) for odd x to be any number in Z in this example and it will be a valid solution.)

Comment: why do you talk about even and odd? @Meiffert

Comment: No specific reason, it was just an example of another function that works.

Answer (score 4):

**Partial answer**

Well,

> $2016=34\times57+78$

and

> $f$ has $57$ in its range, because of the definition. (But we still have to show a number, for which it picks up this value.)

So

> $f(2016)=f(34\times f(y)+78)$ for some $y$, thus it equals 57

Comment: Just let $y=34f(x)+78$ for any $x$, then $f(y)=57$ by definition.